# Passing method call through several unrelated classes

Tags: ios, objective-c

This has a sort of Responder Chain feel to it, but the difference there is, the responder chain is a defined operation on views and view controllers specifically.

Well, I need to pass along a method call through several unrelated classes, and being fairly new to Objective-C, i'm not sure if it would be a hack to define a protocol, and then implement that protocol on every class that the call needs to pass through.

For example...
***ClassA is the delegate to ClassB.

ClassB is the delegate to ClassC***
... hence the 'responder chain' feel.

Does this make sense for the code to pass along a call from C to B to A.

I assume at some point, when the chain gets too long, you'd probably recommend a notification technique instead, but I don't know what that recommended length might be.

```
@protocol DidSomething
  -(void)userDidSomething:(NSString*)something
@end


ClassA <DidSomething>
  -(void)userDidSomething:(NSString*)something
  {
    NSLog(@"The user did something %@",something);
  }


ClassB <DidSomething>
  -(void)userDidSomething:(NSString*)something
  {
    [self.delegate userDidSomething:something];
  }


ClassC <DidSomething>
  -(void)thatWasInteresting
  {
    [self.delegate userDidSomething:@"Cool"];
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.  Nothing wrong with that.   Save for the potential complexity.

You could define it as a protocol, if you want.  Or you could define it as a common abstract superclass (if possible).

Protocols are generally the way to go these days and using `@optional` requires the use of a `respondsToSelector:` test (or `conformsToProtocol:`).

All in all, though, you should be very careful about the use of such a pattern.   Specifically, it implies a lot about the architecture of your application and, thus, you want to make sure the architecture is sound.

Comment: The classes don't have any sort of inheritance relationship between them, so abstract superclass wouldn't apply in this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is using `NSNotificationCenter` to post `NSNotification`s. Object can add themselves as observers. Depending on your needs, this might be a good alternative to passing a message through a chain of delegate.

It is especially useful if more than one object needs to respond to a message.